# What's the pros/cons of updating vs not updating version number on SPFx webparts or customizations?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

In SPFx development, what is the benefits or disadvantages of updating or not updating the version number when updating in the app catalogue?

The best practice appears to be to update it to something higher, but it just seems it complicates the update process, because now you have to touch each site and manually update each customization per site. If you don't, sure the app still gets the latest static resource update automatically, but it doesn't fully upgrade the app in terms of some of its config settings.

Does anyone know?

Thanks